# Wordpress css and ie6

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-6

my website : http://www.equipe94.com have a two column layout and in ie6 the right column is flushed at the button... it look like and inline problem, but even WITH the inline widget.. it's still at the bottom..

any idea to fix a wordpress template to play well with ie6 ?

thanks in advance

**n.b.** 
As mentioned in the comment... my page don't validate... 
after fixing the multiples problems now I validate in XHTML 1.0 Strict... 
but the problem is still there !

Comment: isn't it time IE6 was left to die?

Comment: @Robert when every last corporate client has upgraded, then yes. until then, sadly on it goes... :-)

Comment: i already ditch the iphone / blackberry user.... with there tiny screen it's just a joke... but there is still a 10% ie6.. that i like to keep happy (most of the time)

Comment: Corporate clients won't upgrade until it becomes apparent to laymen that the browser is severely outdated. So yes, leave it to die and they will soon upgrade.

Comment: andre menard: The last thing Quebec needs is more IE6 users... People are painfully slow here to adopt change. Time to drop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.... it's was an hentry that overflow the content box.... ie6 detect it !... in css i have add overflow:hidden then it's ok !.. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few missing closing `</div>` tags that might be the problem: [[Invalid]Markup Validation of   equipe94.com  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.equipe94.com/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.

You also should work with the IE6 specific style sheet that is in your theme at `/headway-166/media/css/ie6.css`

Comment: I have fix all the errors... and I validate... but the problem is still there... any idea ?